# How to check if a char in a 2d array appears more than once? c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm making a board game, and I was just wondering how to search through an array to find an element (let's name it N in this case), and each time N is counted, the counter goes up one. If N connects one side to the other the player wins.
This solution is only for one row of the array, hence why the counter is reset at the start of each 'i' iteration.

```
void board::winner(int x, int y)

{
    int count = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
{
    count = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < row; xaxis++)
    {
        if (arr[i][j] == 'N')
        {
            count++;
        }            
    }

    if (count == col)                  // == to col because we are testing straight lines
    {
        cout << "P2 wins!";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How about `if (count > 1)`?

Comment: BTW, most matrices are declared as `matrix[row][column]`.  Try printing and see how the layout works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Move you initialization of `count` to above the first `for` loop.
2. Move the `if` statement after the end of the first `for` loop.

void board::winner(int x, int y)
{
    int count = 0;

```
for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)

{
    for (int j = 0; j < row; xaxis++)
    {
        if (arr[i][j] == 'N')
        {
            count++;
        }            
    }
}
if (count == col) 
{
    cout << "P2 wins!";
}
```

}

You can make the loop more efficient by terminating the loops after the first duplicate is found:

```
for (int i = 0; i < col; ++i)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < row; ++j)
   {
      if (arr[i][j] == 'N')
      {
         ++count;
         if (count > 1)
         {
            break;
         }
      }
   }
   if (count > 1)
   {
      break;
   }
}
```

The above code will terminate as soon as the first duplicate is found, thus not searching the entire board.